# how to generate codeception code coverage badge on github?

Tags: github, code-coverage, codeception

I'm looking for some automated way to generate a badge with code coverage information in Github repo's README file based on reports created by Codeception. I am aware of hosted services like coverals, but is there a script/library to generate on my own in a travis pipeline?